# Les personnes qu'elle a rencontré(s)?

Tags: pluriel, participe-passé

Bonjour! Voici ma phrase:

> Toutes les personnes que Julie a rencontré dans sa vie ont joués des rôles importants.

Est-ce que le mot rencontré est pluriel ou singulier?

Comment: Au féminin pluriel (rencontrées), c'est une question récurrente sur ce site. Avec l'auxiliaire **avoir**, accord si le COD est placé **avant** le verbe, ce qui est le cas ici.

Answer (score 4):

Il y a deux participes passés dans la phrase :
- rencontré
- joués

Dans le premier cas, Julie a rencontré les personnes. Le complément "les personnes" est situé **avant** le participe "rencontré" qui doit donc être accordé : rencontrées
Dans le deuxième cas, le complément "rôles" est situé **après** le participe "joué", qui ne doit donc pas être accordé et reste au singulier : joué.

Donc :
Toutes les personnes que Julie a rencontrées dans sa vie ont joué des rôles importants.